# How do I create a workflow when the comment field has been updated

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I want to create a workflow when there is a new comment added to an issue tracking ticket.

I have managed to create workflows on SharePoint Designer when a ticket has been created or resolved however I can't work out when a comments field has been updated.

Can you please help?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the workflow action that should happen when the comment is added/changed?

Comment: I am trying to send an email to the end user (requester) that there is a new comment added to the ticket.  I tried the suggestion below """In the workflow editor when you select the condition, the easiest is "if current item:comments is not empty""""" but still not working for me

Answer (score 1):

In the workflow editor when you select the condition, the easiest is "if current item:comments is **not empty**"

Not empty is a category that you can select.

I have also set up in the settings that the workflow runs when an item is created (there might be a case when an item created has got immediately a comment) and when an item is changed (comment is added later).

I have tried this just now and it works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply -  I am trying to send out an email to the end user but it is not sending the email.  The workflow is very simple if current item is not empty email current item email address.  Any other suggestions

Comment: Check if the settings for sending out emails in SP are correct? do you receive alerts? ask the exchange admin if they changed the IP address/port/something of their server

Comment: I receive emails when a new ticket has been created or resolved but not when the comments field is updated.  Not sure.

Comment: see updated pic above, does it look like mine? I only receive emails when there is a comment, either when it is inserted as you create the issue or it is inserted later. I do not receive emails when issue is created with no comments (even tho the end user should receive an email when he logs an issue)

Comment: It has worked now.  I had to change the settings on the column from  Append Changes to Existing Text from Yes to No.  Thanks so much for your help with this

Comment: Although, I would have preferred the first option as it dates and times the comments.  is there a way of setting up a new WorkFlow for when you append the changes.  This time it leaves the comments on the column